# Saving web page as PDF with page title as a 'File name' in IE10

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer-10, save-as

I am using `System dialog` print option to save the web page as PDF using PDF-Xchange Printer 2012.

When the 'Save As' dialog opened, the 'File name' is `Scrum Master - Login.pdf` (page title) in Chrome/Firefox. [Screenshot](http://navayan.com/chrome-firefox-save-as.jpg)

But in IE10 the 'File name' is `81.pdf` [Screenshot](http://navayan.com/ie10-save-as.jpg)

(My project URL is: `localhost:81/test/login.html`)

I want the page title to be taken place in IE10 when saving the page as PDF. 
I haven't get any solution when searched on net :(

Please note, I am not asking for another PDF exporter!